# Meaning of "so much for" and "for the love of"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

These phrases might be easily understandable for others, but I find them difficult to grasp, perhaps because English is not my mother tongue. I have been searching for answers for quite some time, but got even more confused every time I tried to learn the meaning of them, and when and where they are used.

What do these two phrases mean?

Answer (score 3):

I can see why you'd be confused by *so much for*. I found two dictionaries that defined the term, but their definitions are a little tricky to understand.

[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+much+for) says:

> **so much for something**
>   that is the last of something; there is no need to consider something anymore:
>   *It just started raining. So much for our picnic this afternoon*.

[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/so-much-for-sth) says:

> **so much for something**
>   used to express disappointment at the fact that a situation is not as you thought it was:
>   *The car's broken down again. So much for our trip to the seaside.*

Both meanings together sum up how the phrase is used pretty well. If I say, "So much for X!" then that means that I'm not going to think about X anymore; it seemed like a good idea for awhile, but now it's not going to happen.

Let's say a basketball team was losing a game by 25 points at halftime, but managed to tie the game with just one minute left. In the end, though, the other team won. Someone might say,

> Well, so much for that!

In that case, the word *that* would refer to the team's comeback. They almost pulled off a win, but in the end they fell short.

---

As for *for the love of*, [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+love+of) defines that as:

> **for the love of Pete** (or **Mike**, or **God**)
>   An exclamation of surprise, exasperation, or some similar feeling

Going back to the basketball game, let's say the team that was trailing at halftime **did** come back and win the game. The other team's coach might say,

> For the love of God, I can't believe we lost that game!

That phrase doesn't really add any meaning to the sentence, it just adds feeling and emotion to the sentence. I don't think you'll find it used much except in direct quotes.

Comment: Thankyou for explaining their meaning. :) i want to ask one more thing here regarding the phrase "for the love of" this also means 'for the sake of', right?  But what does it mean if we say for the love of chocolates or cates or any other thing for that matter?

Comment: @ArdisEll - I need more context to say. Have you seen it somewhere in particular you can quote or point me to?

Comment: No, I would not say "for the love of" means the same as "for the sake of". First of all, it should be noted that neither of these is "common" usage; both are somewhat rare (but recognizable) colloquialisms. "For the love of" is just as J.R. said--lighthearted exasperation. "For the sake of" is primarily used as an introductory lead-in. "For the sake of argument, let's say..." Or "For the sake of brevity, assume..." It is in no way used out of frustration.

Comment: If I buy all the albums of my favorite singer and I say , for the love of him, would that be correct? And what does it mean here? Because I have seen around the people doing so.

Comment: @Ardis - _I love Paul Simon! I have all his albums. I buy all of Steven King's books, because I love the way he writes_. That kind of construct is just fine. But, I would **not** use "for the love of" when explaining why I'm buying someone's albums or books.

Comment: Its meaning is still unclear to me. I saw a post saying for the love of historical places. Well, that person posted some pictures. What does it mean in that context? Just overwhelmed by the beauty of the historical places? I'm sorry, english is not my native language, so I find it difficult to get the meanings of some words

Comment: @ArdisEll - I wonder if the person writing that post is a native English speaker. I just typed that quote into Google, and got this: `No results found for "for the love of historical places".` But when I change the quote to `"I love visiting historical places"`, I get dozens of hits. As a side note, ELL is the place to ask such questions, so please don't apologize. That said, it would be good to include quotes like the one you saw in future questions. The more context you give, the better we can answer your questions.

Comment: That's probably because that post is on privacy. I could send you a screenshot but sending pictures is not allowed here. Perhaps that person wrote an incorrect sentence, but her English is very good. Anyway, never mind :)

Comment: @ArdisEll - No, I'm not challenging you; I don't need a screenshot. :) I'm just saying this: if it were standard usage, I think we would find more hits on Google. It sounds very odd to me. That said, the word "for" can mean "because", so it's not exactly _wrong_. However, the phrase "for the love of X" usually expresses emotional exasperation, so I think most folks avoid using it to say "because I love X."